# New to Vue.js need help as to why the bars wont update beyond the first command

Tags: html, css, vue.js

The bars won't update with the health score after the first attempt, though if you keep clicking attack eventually the game ends. I get this error on console but don't know what to do about it to fix the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

[Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "click": got undefined

(found in `<Root>`)

```js
new Vue({
    el:'#app',
    data:{

        playerHealth:100,
        monsterHealth:100,
        gameIsRunning:false


    },

    methods:
    {


        
            startGame: function(){
                
                this.gameIsRunning= true;
                this.playerHealth = 100;
                this.monsterHealth = 100;


            },

            attack: function(){
               
                this.monsterHealth -= this.calculateDamage(3,10)

                if(this.checkWin()){
                    return;
                }

                
              


                this.monsterAttacks();


            },

            specialAttack: function(){
                this.monsterHealth -= this.calculateDamage(10,20)

                if(this.checkWin()){
                    return;
                }

                this.monsterAttacks();


            },

            heal: function(){




            },

            giveUP: function(){



            },

            calculateDamage: function(min,max){

                return Math.max(Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1,min);


            },

            checkWin: function(){

                if(this.monsterHealth <= 0){
                    if(confirm('You Won! new Game?')){
                        this.startGame();
                    }else{

                        this.gameIsRunning = false;

                    }
                    return true
                }else if(this.playerHealth <= 0){
                    if(confirm('You Lost! new Game?')){
                        this.startGame();
                    }else{

                        this.gameIsRunning = false;

                    }
                    return true;


                }
                   return false;
                },

            monsterAttacks: function(){
                this.playerHealth -= this.calculateDamage(5,12);
                this.checkWin();


            }



            }

    





        
});
```

```css
.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}

.healthbar {
    width: 80%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: auto;
    transition: width 500ms;
}

.controls, .log {
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px #ccc;
}

.turn {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.log ul {
    list-style: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.log ul li {
    margin: 5px;
}

.log ul .player-turn {
    color: blue;
    background-color: #e4e8ff;
}

.log ul .monster-turn {
    color: red;
    background-color: #ffc0c1;
}

button {
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 12px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px black;
    margin: 10px;
}

#start-game {
    background-color: #aaffb0;
}

#start-game:hover {
    background-color: #76ff7e;
}

#attack {
    background-color: #ff7367;
}

#attack:hover {
    background-color: #ff3f43;
}

#special-attack {
    background-color: #ffaf4f;
}

#special-attack:hover {
    background-color: #ff9a2b;
}

#heal {
    background-color: #aaffb0;
}

#heal:hover {
    background-color: #76ff7e;
}

#give-up {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#give-up:hover {
    background-color: #c7c7c7;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Monster Slayer</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="foundation.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <section class="row">
        <div class="small-6 columns">
            <h1 class="text-center">YOU</h1>
            <div class="healthbar">

                <div 
                    class="healthbar text-center" 
                    style="background-color: green; margin: 0; color: white;"
                    :style="{width: playerHealth + '%'}">
                    {{ playerHealth }}
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="small-6 columns">
            <h1 class="text-center">MONSTER</h1>
            <div class="healthbar">
                <div 
                
                    class="healthbar text-center" 
                    style="background-color: green; margin: 0; color: white;"
                    :style="{width: monsterHealth + '%'}">
                    {{ monsterHealth }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="row controls" v-if="!gameIsRunning">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <button id="start-game" @click="startGame">START NEW GAME</button>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="row controls" v-else>
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <button id="attack" v-on:click="attack">ATTACK</button>
            <button id="special-attack" @click="specialAttack">SPECIAL ATTACK</button>
            <button id="heal" @click="heal">HEAL</button>
            <button id="give-up" @click="giveUp">GIVE UP</button>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="row log">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <ul>
                <li>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
<script src="work.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You just misspell method name in render . giveUP is the method you setup.

Comment: Oh damn...  , totally ignored that part thinking it was unrelated, lesson learned thanks alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method bound to the click handler is giveUp(), while in your methods, it is spelled giveUP(). The discrepancy is likely throwing the warning.